# How do I get the PHP Uploads directory?

Tags: php

I have uploaded a file using HTML / PHP and following is the print_r() of the $_FILES['file'] array:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
    [type] => application/octet-stream
    [tmp_name] => G:\xampp\tmp\php82DB.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 879394
)
```

As you can see above, the temp file is stored in the tmp_name directory. I need to get that directory path using PHP. How do I get it ?

Tried using `sys_get_temp_dir()` but this is what it returns me.

I do NOT want to get the directory from the array or from the file upload data. I want to dynamically get the php file uploads directory using a function.

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Comment: What do you need this path for? That directory shouldn't be any of our business on PHP level except for precisely the files that have been uploaded there.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$tmp_dir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') ? ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') : sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Answer (score 2):

Php file upload temporary directory is a php config variable located on php.ini file.

You can get the variable config value by using `ini_get` function.

`$path = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
// your code here`

Answer (score 1):

```
$upload_dir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
```