# getting temporary file path using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

is there any possible way to fetch the temporary file path of the file uploaded by

```
<input type="file"/>
```

and then send it to PHP via ajax and getting the file there and store it

explanation with the code will be helpful
thankyou

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. I can think of an approach, but it is stupidly complex and pointless. You seem to have  a bad case of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to send my form data with files uploaded to the server in a complete JSON format using Ajax but I don't wanna use javascript formdata object to achieve it

Comment: Then you need to read the file data. The path to the file is irrelevant.

Comment: how can i read the file data can u please help me out with it

Answer (score 0):

There is no temporary file/path on client side which could be found via Javascript. You are sending the file (the binary data) with a HTTP request which will let the server create a temporary file.

Of course you could add the path in the response which is generated by the server/php. This can be done by getting the config `upload_tmp_dir` or calling  `sys_get_temp_dir`.

You can find a more detailed answer here: [How do I get the PHP Uploads directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511610/how-do-i-get-the-php-uploads-directory)

Answer (score 0):

***(edited to not use `FormData`, although I highly recommend doing that over this)***

**javascript:**

first a base64 file encoding function:

```
function getBase64(file, callback) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file[0].files[0])
   reader.onload = () => {
       callback(reader.result);
   };
}
```

now execute this code when the user clicks the upload button:

```
var data;
getBase64($('input:file'), (r) => { data = r });
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_php_file.php", // Url to which the request is send
    method: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
    data: { file: data }
});
```

**php:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['file'])) {
        $data = $_POST['file'];
        file_put_contents('img.jpg', base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data)));
    }
?>
```

Comment: The problem is he doesn't want to use FormData

Comment: Alright gonna edit in a little bit probably.

Comment: Edited it to base64 encode the image and upload the encoded string.